# Tikz: PDF Preview: Jagged Lines with Cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, rendering

In the following code, the PDF preview (Acrobat) renders jagged diagonal line in the first case (with cycle), but smooth diagonal line in the second. Why could that be?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (4, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (4, 3);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (4, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (4, 3);
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can confirm this strange behavior. In fact under Acrobat 8 (Windows) `(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A)` is smooth, but `(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle` and `(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A) --cycle` are not smooth. With Sumatra there is no difference between the lines.

Comment: What am I supposed to be looking at in the image? Neither looks jagged. @Kpym What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, you mean what looks like differences in anti-aliasing? Probably a question better put to Adobe.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably due to the aliasing handling of Acrobat. I would like to speculate that when closed with `cycle` the path is considered to be a single object and aliased altogether losing precision. And you might be seeing the effect of GPU vs. CPU anti-aliasing.

However this is only a display problem and there is nothing jagged by the graphics themselves. You can turn on/off or modify antialiasing options on Acrobat.

You can try your chances on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ for a more thorough analysis on your file.

Comment: Didn't know that there is gpu and cpu anti aliasing in Adobe.