# Low Quality of TikZ grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, coordinates, pixelated

When I create a rotated 3D coordinate system in TikZ with a grid, it looks kind of bad and pixelated. The slanted x-axis looks fine, so it's not due to the rotation. I've also varied the line thickness with no effect.

[image]

Even when zooming really close on the PDF, the staircase effect remains.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{255, 187, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
    \definecolor{mgrau3}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9 ,thick, tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={very thin,mgrau3}]
    \foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,1}
    \foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,1}
    {
        \draw[grid] (\x,0) -- (\x,1);
        \draw[grid] (-0,\y) -- (1,\y);
    }
    \draw[->,mgelb](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)
        node[right]{$x$}
        node[midway, below, sloped](TextNode){Beschichtungsrichtung};
    \draw[->,mblau](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)
        node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[->,mturkis](0,0,0) -- (0,0,0.8)
        node[right]{$z$}
        node[midway, above, sloped](TextNode){Baurichtung};
    \shade[ball color = mgrau1] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
    \draw[thin] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That “staircase effect” is viewer-dependent. The lines are drawn as continuous lines in the PDF (vector format). The effect you see is called “aliasing”, and is caused by how your PDF viewer assigns colour to different pixels on your screen. Try a different viewer

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik this issue seems to be present on several viewers, I tried OPs MWE on Evince, Okular, Xpdf, Acrobat Reader, GhostView, LibreOffice Draw, and Inkscape, and they all show the aliasing.

Comment: @Marijn Yeah, I also tried Sumatra and the Firefox, Chrome, and <s>Internet Explorer</s> Edge viewers and they don't seem to have a good anti-aliasing. Seems to be that added to the line in the MWE being close to horizontal. Maybe if OP could rotate the picture a bit more...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik According to what I find the issue disappears if one draws the grid with the `grid` path construction. I checked Preview and Acrobat Reader. The lines have the same slope as in the OP's example. This seems to tell us that it is not the slope.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't have those viewers available right now, but with Okular the aliasing is less visible, so it probably looks better in Acrobat. Not sure what's the practical difference in the PDF output though...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Just to let you know you lost me. I do not understand the last comment.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry, sometimes me no speak good ;-) What I meant is that the `grid` path construction is (I believe) just a fancy shortcut to draw a bunch of lines in one then another direction, so there should be (in theory) no difference in the PDF (low-level `moveto`, `lineto`, etc.) draw instructions with one method or the other, so the way the PDF viewer _should not_ change. In short, the viewer doesn't know you used `grid` instead of `\foreach`, right? Or does `grid` uses some special PDF magic different than `\draw (here) -- (there);`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Well, in theory, yes, but in reality it seems that they are quite a bit different. (There are some obvious differences between the two such as the line joins. But yes, I also do not really understand why the antialiasing is so different.)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361098/tikz-pdf-preview-jagged-lines-with-cycle is also an interesting example, the drawing commands are likely to be very similar, but the result is different.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The reason is actually much simpler: the lines got drawn several times.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ah :-) Nice find!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about drawing a real grid in the xy plane? This fixes the problem. Why? see below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{255, 187, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
    \definecolor{mgrau3}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9 ,thick, tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={very thin,mgrau3}]
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
     \draw[grid] (0,0) grid[step=0.2] (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[->,mgelb](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)
        node[right]{$x$}
        node[midway, below, sloped](TextNode){Beschichtungsrichtung};
    \draw[->,mblau](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)
        node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[->,mturkis](0,0,0) -- (0,0,0.8)
        node[right]{$z$}
        node[midway, above, sloped](TextNode){Baurichtung};
    \shade[ball color = mgrau1] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
    \draw[thin] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the problem with your approach? You draw each grid line 6 times because you nest the loop. If you just use the loops once, i.e. draw each grid line precisely once, the problem disappears (almost) completely.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{255, 187, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
    \definecolor{mgrau3}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9 ,thick, tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={very
thin,mgrau3}]
    \foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,1}
    {
        \draw[grid] (\x,0) -- (\x,1);
    }
    {\foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,1}        
        \draw[grid] (-0,\y) -- (1,\y);
    }
    \draw[->,mgelb](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)
        node[right]{$x$}
        node[midway, below, sloped](TextNode){Beschichtungsrichtung};
    \draw[->,mblau](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)
        node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[->,mturkis](0,0,0) -- (0,0,0.8)
        node[right]{$z$}
        node[midway, above, sloped](TextNode){Baurichtung};
    \shade[ball color = mgrau1] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
    \draw[thin] (0.5,0.5,0.25) circle (0.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that you can rewrite the loop as

```
\foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,1}
{
    \draw[grid] (\x,0) -- (\x,1);
    \draw[grid] (-0,\x) -- (1,\x);
}
```